# AWS: Unable to login

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are having AWS server for our corporate, which is having multiple admins. So 4-5 people are accessing/using same .pem file to login/upload to server. Problem is whenever we are trying to login through ssh/putty it hangs without any login. The only option left is to restart the EC2 instance frequently. But I think there has to be some other procedure which may safely allow us to login without hanging putty/ssh terminal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your IP address whitelisted in the security group which is attached to the EC2 instance or does it work after a restart?

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with word whit-listing much. We have created Elastic IP and security group consist of 3 rules ssh, http, https whose source is from anywhere. And yes whenever putty/terminal hangs after EC2 instance restart everything backs to normal. But we are facing it daily frequently.

Comment: as you said port 22 is open from everywhere or is it restricted to some specific ip address ? Also it would not be issue if multiple user logs into ec2 at same time. Are you capping any Limits that causes instance to go in-responsive you can check ec2 logs and also metrics on ec2 dashboard.

Comment: No, port 22 is open from everywhere not restricted to some specific ip address. Instance Limits - Running On-Demand t2.medium instances
limit: 20.

Comment: Networking Limits - EC2-VPC Elastic IPs limit:5 . These limits are not set by us, may be some default configuration.